# How to disable spotlight on fat32 USB drive permanently without using .metadata_never_index?

Tags: spotlight

When I plugin a FAT32 USB drive, MacOS will create two directires named `.fseventsd` and `.Spotlight-V100`.

This is because of spotlight indexing.

I tried to use `sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/<disk_name>/` to disable the indexing, but the indexing will be renabled next time I plug in the drive.

**Requirement:** I will share FAT32 USB drives with someone anonymously. So I don't want anyone to know any of my information including which OS I am using.

I found I could create `.metadata_never_index` file on the USB drive to prevent spotlight indexing, but this way will tell others I am using MacOS so I can not use it.

I don't want any extra files and folder ever created, because even if I remove them, those files will be recoverable by some recovery programs.

Wiping those files/folders securely with 3 passes everytime will be too much and I want to avoid.

I even tried to disable spotlight temporarily with the following cml, but failed:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
Unload failed: 150: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged
```

If possible, I don't want to disable System Integrity Protection.

Thus, are there any ways (is that possible) to not index any FAT32 USB drive? No files/folders including `.fseventsd`, `.Spotlight-V100`, and `.metadata_never_index` should ever be created. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sure this must have been asked before but my google-fu is only green belt today;)) Basically, you cannot stop it, you can only delete it. There's an app called [Blue Harvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/) which does this specifically for non-Mac & network drives.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks a lot for the reply. So the answer to my question is not possible on MacOS then. It seems I have to switch back to Linux OS for such job... What a pity!

Comment: What kind of files are you sharing? For example, PDFs created on your Mac would have PDF metadata indicating the creating app and so tells other person your OS. The same would be true of PDFs created on Linux - I assume you would want to hide that too.

Comment: @Gilby thanks for your reminder. I know how to handle other files properly. so that is not my concern. I am sharing executables for all different platforms (linux, windows, macos) etc.. I knew how to remove metadata from other files too. My only concern right now is spotlight indexing which is evil to me.